# Sql identity column (ID) is not incrementing on insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I created a new table in existing SQL database to hold files uploaded.  Every row is getting inserted with zero as the ID.  It is not incrementing.  What am I doing wrong? **UPDATE:** BTW I did research this before I posted.  I searched on SO (here) and googled. Nothing I found explained or solved my issue and I didn't want to clutter my post up (which now I have):(.

Table structure is this:

```
Table: tblFileUploads
Columns: 
  ID int not null (PK, IDENTITY 1,1)
  Name nvarchar (100)
  ContentType varchar(50)
  Size bigint
  Data varbinary(max)
  FirmID int
```

Stored Procedure (Updated based on comments received --still not setting ID though)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUploadedFiles] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Name nvarchar(100),
    @ContentType varchar(50),
    @Size bigint,
    @Data varbinary(max),
    @FirmId int 
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.tblFileUploads (Name, ContentType, Size, Data, FirmID)
    VALUES (@Name, @ContentType, @Size, @Data, @FirmId)

END
```

aspx.cs code to insert to sql:

```
public void InsertFile ( string filename, string contentType, int size, byte[]data)
    {
        //create new sqlconnection
        using (SqlConnection Sqlcon = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdInsertFile  = new SqlCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    //firm exists  
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ActiveFirmId"] != null)
                    {
                        OpenConnection(Sqlcon);
                        //Sqlcon.Open();

                        //Insert tblFileUploads
                        cmdInsertFile.Connection = Sqlcon;
                        cmdInsertFile.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        cmdInsertFile.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmdInsertFile.CommandText = "InsertUploadedFiles";                     

                        //Filename
                        cmdInsertFile.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar,100));
                        cmdInsertFile.Parameters["@Name"].Value = filename;

                        //Content Type
                        cmdInsertFile.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar,50));
                        cmdInsertFile.Parameters["@ContentType"].Value = contentType;

                        //Size
                        cmdInsertFile.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Size", SqlDbType.Int));
                        cmdInsertFile.Parameters["@Size"].Value = size;

                        //Data
                        cmdInsertFile.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Data", SqlDbType.VarBinary));
                        cmdInsertFile.Parameters["@Data"].Value = data;//DBNull.value;

                        //FirmId
                        cmdInsertFile.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@FirmId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, false, ((System.Byte)(0)), ((System.Byte)(0)), "FirmId", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Original, null));
                        cmdInsertFile.Parameters["@FirmId"].Value = HttpContext.Current.Session["ActiveFirmId"].ToString();

                        cmdInsertFile.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        Sqlcon.Close();
                    }

                    //new firm
                    else
                    {
                        Label lblWarning = new Label();
                        lblWarning.Text = "Please Save new firm before you may upload their application documents.";
                    }

                }//end try

              catch (SqlException sqlEx)
                {
                    WriteToEventLog("SqlException Message: " + sqlEx.Message + ", " + sqlEx.Source + ", " + sqlEx.LineNumber);
                }//end of catch

            }//end of 2nd using

        }//end of 1st using

    }//end of method
```

UPDATE: Code that retrieves the values on upload button click.  I thought it was irrelevent to my SQL question since the data is being captured and INSERTed, it's the identity column that is not working.

```
   protected void btnUploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //check file extension
        Boolean fileOK = false;

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {            
                //Verify that file to upload is PDF format
                string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();

                string[] allowedExtensions = {".pdf"};

                for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
                    {
                        fileOK = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Label1.Text = "Cannot accept files of this type. Please scan document to PDF and try upload again.";
                    }
                }
            }//end if (hasfile)
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file.";
        } //end else

        if (fileOK)
        {
            try
            {

                HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files;

                foreach (string fileTagName in files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[fileTagName];
                    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {

                        int size = file.ContentLength;

                        string name = file.FileName;

                        int position = name.LastIndexOf("\\");

                        name = name.Substring(position + 1);

                        string contentType = file.ContentType;

                        byte[] fileData = new byte[size];

                        file.InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, size);

//pass to database
                        SqlConnLib inserter = new SqlConnLib();
                        inserter.InsertFile(name, contentType, size, fileData);
                    }
                }
            }//try

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Display failure message
                Label1.Text = "ERROR Message: " + ex.Message.ToString() +
                    ", <br />Source:  " + ex.Source +
                    ", <br />TargetSite: " + ex.TargetSite +
                    ", <br />StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace;
            } //end catch 
        }//if

        }//end method
```

Comment: I do not believe that `id` is declared either as `identity` or `primary key`, because the behavior you describe is impossible in either case.  The only other question is:  how are you looking at the results?  Maybe the problem is with that query.

Comment: check that your ID column is an identity.

Comment: try this command SET IDENTITY_INSERT db.schema.tablename Off;

Comment: It is identity if I could upload an image I would show you.

Comment: Where's your code that queries the data and returns 0s? Why is your table not prefixed with a schema (e.g. `dbo.tblFileUploads`) - could be you're looking at two different tables? Do any of your connection strings include `User Instance` or `AttachDbFileName` - could be you're looking at two different copies of the database?

Comment: @Aaron I am using dbo.tblFileUploads. (I will add it to my SP and try again).  Connection string do not include User Instance or AttachDBfileName.  I am using a test database made by restoring production copy to a different name.

Comment: And what is the exact code that is showing you that every row has a zero for the id? Also nothing to do with your issue, but why is `@Data` defined as `varbinary` and not `varbinary(max)`? See [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: @markg, I tried your suggestion but I just noticed you changed it to "Off", I tried "ON" and that didn't work.

Comment: @Aaron FYI I updated my post with the code that retrieves the data.  I did use varbinary(max) in the table but I see I didn't in the SP (will fix this). There is no "exact" code showing me the zero's, I am querying the table after I run the code to see that all rows are assigned ID=0. Rows are getting inserted with correct data, just wrong identity id. I'll read the blog when I can (I am prevented from blog posts from work). Thank you

Comment: I don't see where this code checks the id *after* the upload. Have you looked directly in the table in a query window, instead of using your code? My guess is the data is fine, but the code isn't doing what you think it's doing. You should add an output parameter to your stored procedure, and set that value to `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` immediately after the insert, and then retrieve that output parameter in your code.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you for the critique. I've been querying from SQL 2008 via Management Studio viewing rows in the table after running an insert from code. Thanks for the good debugging advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table isn't using an identity field for ID, or your data isn't being inserted (which doesn't sound like the case.)

You should expand your table catalog, and expand 'keys' for your desired table. You should see  your identity column there. Double click on the key, and go to the column properties, it should be allow nulls = no, default value = blank, type = int, identity specification yes, (under identity specification) is identity = yes, identity increment = 1, identity seed = 1

If these are not true statements, you did not create the identity correctly, and you should start over with the table.

```
create table database.dbo.demo
(
    id int not null identity(1, 1)
, name nvarchar(100)
, contenttype varchar(50)
, size bigint
, data varbinary(max)
, firmid int
)

insert into database.dbo.demo (name, contenttype, size, data, firmid)
select name, contenttype, size, data, firmid from database.dbo.oldtable
```

Comment: OMG!!! That is SO cool.  I must've messed up when I created the table.  I created it originally by right-clicking Tables, New Table...P.S.All the rows came in with IDs starting with "1" by using your script.

Comment: I assume you mean 'Starting at one, and increment by 1 for each row' - which is the desired behavior, I believe. The sql simply creates an identical table, and inserts into the new database all the data from the old database. When you import tables from scripts using export/import methods, you need to recreate indexes that existed on the original table, and the same usually applies for constraints. If you use the table creator, you must be sure to specify the correct information. See additional documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Comment: I just had to post one more time because now my original table has the identity columns numbered too! (as expected [1,2,3...])! AND my Data column contains the binary data correctly which was another issue I was working on. Interesting.

Comment: To be clear, the process listed above in the answer would have had no impact on the original table. Something else you were working on corrected the original problem. (Clarifying for any future readers of this question)

Comment: What may have triggered the correction in identity column behavior: it was after closing SQL 2008 Management Studio and reopening it that I noticed the change in the orginal database.

Answer (score 1):

I think making the matching fields in the stored procedure would be solved.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUploadedFiles] 

    @Name nvarchar(100),
    @ContentType varchar(50),
    @Size bigint,
    @Data varbinary,
    @FirmId int 
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO tblFileUploads (Name,ContentType,Size,Data,FirmId)
    VALUES (@Name, @ContentType, @Size, @Data, @FirmId)

END
```

Comment: well good catch! I can't believe I missed that but even after including it, it still inserted row with zero as identity.